# Как делать картинки Material Design

Tags: дизайн

Где и как можно рисовать подобные картинки? Какой вид графики лучше использовать?  Нужно, чтобы картинки были качественные, но весили минимум.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле это не фотошоп, а генератор изображений, поддерживаемый гуглом. Вот [ссылка](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0&foreColor=607d8b%2C0&crop=0&backgroundShape=bevel&backColor=e91e63%2C100&effects=none).

Там можно выбирать цвет, геометрические формы материального изображения и т.д. в общем заходите и смотрите)

---

Гугл убрали генератор выше, его больше нет, но я нашел аналог. Возможно, гугл снова включит тот генератор, а пока пользуемся [альтернативой](http://www.stringsistemas.com/materialgenerator.html).

Comment: Класс, и не знала!

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko спасибо) кстати да, очень полезная штука для фона для разных элементов) особенно для таких немощей, как я, которые не разбираются в создании графики)

Comment: нифига себе! огромное спасибо)